# Mapbox GL JS: How to position graticules labels on edge of map?

Tags: javascript, dom, coordinates, mapbox, label

I'm working on a map in Mapbox studio to use on a web app with Mapbox GL JS. I'm looking for some advice on how to go about displaying coordinates on the edge of my map like classic printed maps:

[image]

I'm currently playing with these labels positioned on the lines themselves running through the map (using a preset style and graticules dataset layer), but I'm hoping to fix these to the edge (latitude across the bottom X axis and longitude down the right).

[image]

This is a design mockup of the map I'm trying to build, and I've constructed all elements besides the map border coordinates:

[image]

I'm very confident with interacting with a Mapbox style from JS etc (data-driven styling, accessing layers, features, DOM elements etc), but I'm not sure how to approach this.

Ideally every 15 degrees will have a marker, and this could potentially scale in/out as the user zooms. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm looking to do exactly the same thing.